# Legend in Geoserver generates wrong image

Tags: geoserver, style, geoserver-css-module

I have written the Style in CSS, in Geoserver. Following is the code

```
/*@title Cresta HighRes*/
    *{
    stroke-width:1;
      stroke:#686868;
      fill:#e1e1e1;
    }

    [@scale < 1500000] {
        label:[cresta_hr_id];
        label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
        font-family: "Calibri";
        font-fill: #ffffff;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12;
      halo-color:#787878;
      halo-radius:2;
      }
```

This creates a Legend graphic [image]
where "Cresta High Res" is appearing twice. I want it to appear only once like this [image]. What should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is "cascading", so the rules are getting mixed with each other, generating two rules with the same title:

- First rule covers 1:1 to 1:15k, and has the label and the stroke
- Second rule activates past 1:15k, and only has the stroke

See also:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cascading.html

I can think of two options:

- Try to use "flat" mode as described in the page above, thus disabling cascading (warning, it's still somewhat buggy)
- Pass a scale value in GetLegendGraphic call so that it knows which rules is active at the current scale, see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html

Comment: I used the @mode "Flat"; option in my css and it works for some styles and it is buggy for others like you mentioned. When i mentioned a scale in the GetLegendGraphic call i did not make any difference in my legend graphic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the standard behaviour for the CSS (and SLD) legend generator. If you have a specific image that you need to use then you can add that as the legend to the style, using the `Add Legend` button on the `Data` tab of the style editing page.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*@title Cresta HighRes*/
*{
stroke-width:1;
  stroke:#686868;
  fill:#e1e1e1;
}

[@scale < 1500000] {
    label:[cresta_hr_id];
    label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    font-fill: #ffffff;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12;
  halo-color:#787878;
  halo-radius:2;
  }
```